# prove a number-theory with Mertens's results prove that $\sum_{p<x} \frac{(\log p)^2}{p}=\frac12(\log x)^2+O(\log x)$

Tags: number-theory

Using only Mertens’s result (prime number theory not allowed here), prove that
$$\sum_{p<x}  \frac{(\log p)^2}{p}=\frac12(\log x)^2+O(\log x)$$

can please someone do it? i don't really know where to start :(
with the prime number theory is ok but without it I think not.

First theorem
$$\sum_{p\leq n}  \frac{\log p}{p}- \log n\leq2$$

Second theorem

$$ \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sum _{p\leq n}{\frac {1}{p}}-\ln \ln n-M\right)=0,  $$
where $$M={\frac {4}{\ln(n+1)}}+{\frac {2}{n\ln n}}$$

Third theorem

$$lim _{n\to \infty }\ln n\prod _{p\leq n}\left(1-{\frac {1}{p}}\right)=e^{-\gamma }$$
where $\gamma=0,57721$ .

Comment: You’ve only stated half of the first theorem.  The quantity in question is bounded in *absolute value* by 2, so it’s also bounded below by $-2$.

Comment: How would you do this using Prime Number Theorem?  If your answer is “partial summation”, then why not do exactly the same starting from Mertens?  If you’ve tried this, please include your efforts in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using summation by parts
$$ \sum_{p\leq N}\frac{\log^2(p)}{p}=\log(N)\sum_{p\leq N}\frac{\log(p)}{p}-\sum_{n\leq N-1}\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\sum_{p\leq n}\frac{\log(p)}{p} $$
Mertens' theorem gives $\sum_{p\leq N}\frac{\log(p)}{p}=\log(N)+O(1)$ and $\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$, hence
$$ \sum_{p\leq N}\frac{\log^2(p)}{p}=\log^2(N)+O(\log N)-\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{\log n}{n}=\frac{1}{2}\log^2(N)+O(\log N).$$

Comment: yeeee i've done something similar after that someone put a comment and after deleted it. But he gave me a nice hint. Thank to everybody <3